# Change Default Version Swagger Location

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, swashbuckle

Using Swashbuckle in conjuntion with `c.MultipleApiVersions((apiDesc, version) =>`... the result is our swagger file resides at eg: https://host/api/swagger/docs/{version}.  I would like to actually have the swagger file at https://host/api/{version}/swagger.  Is it possible the I can set this up in my SwaggerConfig `.EnableSwagger()`?

This would allow for the following Urls :

http://host/api/v1/swagger/

http://host/api/v2/swagger/

Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To do that way, you can update the swaggerconfig file as shown below:

```
.EnableSwagger("{apiVersion}/swagger", c =>
        {
            c.MultipleApiVersions(
                (vc) =>
                {
                    vc.Version("v2", "Swashbuckle Dummy API V2");
                    vc.Version("v1", "Swashbuckle Dummy API V1");
                });
        });
```

Comment: Awesome thanks.  Is a {apiVersion} a known token available for replacement?   What other tokens are there.. docs?

Comment: I think you can refer to their documentation - https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle#custom-routes

Answer (score 4):

Just for further references in asp.net core 2.2 it will lokk like this

```
app.UseSwagger(options =>
        {
            options.RouteTemplate = "docs/{documentName}/docs.json";

        });

        app.UseSwaggerUI(options =>
            {
                //Build a swagger endpoint for each discovered API version  
                foreach (var description in provider.ApiVersionDescriptions.OrderByDescending(x=>x.ApiVersion).AsList())
                {
                    options.SwaggerEndpoint($"/docs/{description.GroupName}/docs.json", description.GroupName);
                }
                options.RoutePrefix = "docs";
            }
        );
```

in which `provider` is `IApiVersionDescriptionProvider` injected by DI